# EEPLUS AutoFitColumns() -object reference exception

Tags: c#, excel, exception

Im trying to do some actions on excel worksheet, the excel loaded perferct, but when im tying to AutoFitColumns() i got exception.

the excel isnot null after loading
[image: the excel isnot null after loading]

and the cells isnot null
[image]

but i got exception on AutoFitColumns();
[image]

the stackTrace error

```
   at OfficeOpenXml.Drawing.ExcelPicture..ctor(ExcelDrawings drawings, XmlNode node)
   at OfficeOpenXml.Drawing.ExcelDrawing.GetDrawing(ExcelDrawings drawings, XmlNode node)
   at OfficeOpenXml.Drawing.ExcelDrawings.AddDrawings()
   at OfficeOpenXml.Drawing.ExcelDrawings..ctor(ExcelPackage xlPackage, ExcelWorksheet sheet)
   at OfficeOpenXml.ExcelWorksheet.get_Drawings()
   at OfficeOpenXml.ExcelRangeBase.AutoFitColumns(Double MinimumWidth, Double MaximumWidth)
   at OfficeOpenXml.ExcelRangeBase.AutoFitColumns()
   at AmsalemLogic.Domain.Caching.InfraStructure.ExcelHelper.MarkRows(MemoryStream stream, List`1 RowsNumToMark, List`1 problematicRowsNumToMark, Dictionary`2 DuplicationToMark, Int32 start, Int32 end, Int32 width, Boolean rightToLeft)
   at AmsalemLogic.NewLogic.Classes.Reports.SupplierPayment.SupplierPaymentControlHelper.PerformMatching(MemoryStream stream, SupplierPaymentControlResult SupplierPaymentTable, String Supplier, String CurrencyCode) in C:\AmsaemLogic\AmsalemLogic.NewLogic\Classes\Reports\SupplierPayment\SupplierPaymentControlHelper.cs:line 48
   at AmsalemLogic.ReservationReportService.ExecuteSupplierPaymentControl(SupplierPaymentControlParameters reportParameters) in C:\AmsaemLogic\AmsalemLogic3_1\WebMethodes\ReservationReportService.svc.vb:line 799
   at SyncInvokeExecuteSupplierPaymentControl(Object , Object[] , Object[] )
   at System.ServiceModel.Dispatcher.SyncMethodInvoker.Invoke(Object instance, Object[] inputs, Object[]& outputs)
   at System.ServiceModel.Dispatcher.DispatchOperationRuntime.InvokeBegin(MessageRpc& rpc)
```

Comment: Did you  click "View Details" , then expand StackTrace? Copy the contents of that pane into your question.

Comment: sorry i forgot.i added the stackTrace.